# What exactly is the Canvas View relationship?

Tags: android, view, canvas

I'm looking at this example of [how to drag things around the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700550/is-it-possible-to-move-components-around-the-screen-using-the-standard-android-a) and my only point of confusion is what exactly IS the Canvas c object being passed in?

Is this View occupying the entire screen? What if it's set as the child to a Layout? Are there multiple canvases (one for each display item) or is there one overall Canvas upon which all things are rendered?

I'm having a hard time picturing what's happening beneath the hood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Canvas is the entire drawable area of the screen.  You're supposed to stay within the bounds that the view has set, but in reality there's nothing stopping you from drawing all over.